# If $Y$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, find $p(|y-\mu|>2\sigma)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, normal-distribution

If $Y$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, find $p(|y-\mu|>2\sigma)$

$\underline{Attempt}$

Given that $Y$ is normal distribution thus $z=\dfrac{y-\mu}{\sigma}$,

$$p(|y-\mu|>2\sigma)=p(|z\sigma|>2\sigma)=p(-2>z>2)$$ by using table I got

$p(|y-\mu|>2\sigma)=2p(z>2)=0.0456$

Is that correct I feel not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a typo, it should be $$P(|Z|>2)=P(Z<-2\cup Z>2)=2P(Z>2)=2\times 0.0228=0.0456$$
So, it is *approximately* correct since the table is approximate.

P.S. Using uppercase letters for denoting random variables is better since lowercase letters are typically used for scalars.

Comment: Thank you for your informations

Comment: It wasn't a typo $|Z|>2 \iff-2>Z>2$ is that wrong

Comment: What do you think about -2 > 2?

Comment: Oh funny :) thank you mention it